# ClamAV detected trojan. What are the next steps?

Tags: kali-linux, malware

OS: Arch linux lts kernel.

Today I ran clamAV on my computer and it yielded an infected file with code Unix.Trojan.MSShellcode-10.

I then performed a [Virus Total Analysis](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/ae6391c132598358bb1409b30f901e5de2158994aa8ab92eb332fdc8884922a2/detection) of the file. 2 out of 69 vendors identify this as a malicious file, being them google and clamAV

This file is a chunk of a kali linux distribution image for vmware that I downloaded through a torrent, pointed by the official website.

Running `sigtool --find-sigs Unix.Trojan.MSShellcode-10 | awk '{ print $2 }' | sigtool --decode-sigs` I get the decoded signature: `ruby -rsocket -ropenssl -e 'exit if fork;c=OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSock`

I didn't notice any unusual behaviour in my computer so far and I downloaded the file like two weeks ago

So, is there a way to know if this file is truly malicious, given that virus total result is not uniform at all?

If it is malicious, what are my options, other than the obvious system wipe?

Comment: If it's pointed to by the official website, maybe you should talk to the Kali people. Also, did the thought that a pentesting distro (which is literally meant to do nothing but get into other people's network; whoever proposes to use it as anything else but that is a fool that didn't read [kali's own documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/)) might actually contain malicious software to be *deployed* somewhere else cross your mind?

Comment: That is a good hypothesis that I did not consider. Thank you for your answer

Comment: After deeper thoughts, I believe that this is not the case. A chunk of the vmware image of the OS would unlikely contain only the piece of malware with this suspicious signature. I am not an expert at all so this thinking can be flawed. Feel free to correct me if that's the case

Comment: I said what I was thinking about exactly that in my previous comment.